# Using Enabled Variable in VMware vCenter Inventory Plugin for Ansible Tower

Tags: ansible, vmware, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

Due to licensing restrictions of Ansible Tower, I only want to activate certain hosts. Currently, all hosts are pulled into an inventory using VMware vCenter. I want to use the enabled variable function to import only hosts with the variable *"config.guestId"* and the value *"rhel8_64Guest"* or at least only enable them. But this doesn't seem to work quite, even in debug I don't see any *enabled_var* or *enabled_value* set. Ultimately I would like to restrict to RHEL 8 only (and RHEL 7 systems, gladly only those which are poweredOn).
Basically I want to use something like according to this [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/vmware_scenarios/vmware_inventory_filters.html#requirements) just for [Ansible Tower VMWare-sourced Inventories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/inventories.html#ug-source-vmvcenter).

```
filters:
- config.guestId == "rhel8_64Guest"
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your inventory? According to docs ( https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/vmware_scenarios/vmware_inventory_filters.html#requirements ) it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I added some information to my initial post. I want to use the filter feature from the VMware dynamic inventory plugin in the "stock" Ansible Tower Inventories Source section (see attached screenshot from the Ansible Tower GUI).